# How do I maintain data types when copying document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to make a change to use a generated ObjectId instead of String I was using but the field data type changes from Int to Double.

For example say we have a document

```
{_id: "Product Name", count: 415 }
```

Now I want to create a document

```
{_id: "some object id", name: "Product Name", count: 415 }
```

I am using similar code below but it makes the count a Double.

```
var cursor = db.products.find()
cursor.forEach(function(item) 
{
    var old_id= item._id;

    item.name = old_id;
    delete item._id; 

    db.products.insert(item); 
    db.products.remove({_id:old_id}); 
});
```

I can add this in the loop:  item.count = NumberInt( item.count) to make sure it's an Int but
I really don't want to do this for each field that I have.

Is there anyway to do this without manually having to cast them?  I don't understand why it takes an Int and turns it into a Double.  I know Double is the default but the fields that I am working with are already Integers.

Comment: I wrote a quick java class to do the same thing but it's much slower.

Comment: @KarenS. Yep, using a language with native support for integers is the way to go here to preserve the data type. Use the bulk API from Java to improve performance.

Comment: "I don't understand why it takes an Int and turns it into a Double." - because there are no integers in javascript.

Comment: Ah okay that explains it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if I understand you, your documents look like this:

```js
{ "_id" : "Apple", "count" : 187 }
{ "_id" : "Google", "count" : 123 }
{ "_id" : "Amazon", "count" : 325 }
{ "_id" : "Oracle", "count" : 566 }
```

You can use the [Bulk Api](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) to *update* your collection.

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
Var count = 0;

db.collection.aggregate([{ $project: { '_id': 0, 'name': '$_id', 'count': 1 }}]).forEach(function(doc){
    bulk.find({'_id': doc.name}).remove(); 
    bulk.insert(doc); 
    count++; 
    if (count % 1000 == 0){
        // Execute per 1000 operations and re-init.
        bulk.execute(); 
        bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(); 
    }})

// Clean up queues
if (count % 1000 != 0){ 
    bulk.execute(); 
}
```

Then:

```
db.collection.find()
```

Yields the following documents:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55a7e2c7eb68594275546c7c"), "count" : 187, "name" : "Apple" } 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55a7e2c7eb68594275546c7d"), "count" : 123, "name" : "Google" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55a7e2c7eb68594275546c7e"), "count" : 325, "name" : "Amazon" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55a7e2c7eb68594275546c7f"), "count" : 566, "name" : "Oracle" }
```

> Is there anyway to do this without manually having to cast them? I don't understand why it takes an Int and turns it into a Double. I know Double is the default but the fields that I am working with are already Integers.

You really don't need to worry about that if you are using the shell but as pointed out in the comment you can always  use a language with native support for integers to preserve the data type.

Comment: Thanks for your response!